# importing google ads to android project get me error

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I just updated android studio to arctic fox update and now I can't import dependency for AdView or MapView in my project I get this error when I trying to add any of them
[Click here to show screenshot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UTmv.jpg)

and this is my dependencies included in my project
[Click here to show screenshot of dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MrfU.jpg)

please how can I solve this problem

Comment: try to add com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0 in your dependencies

Comment: when I add this line application crashed with no errors in logcat

Comment: After adding the dependency, follow integration steps from developer docs. Most probably you would’ve missed adding APPLICATION_ID tag in your Manifest for AdMob.

Comment: well, it's worked